# How do I create movement with isKeyPressed?

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to make a simple football game, but I'm having trouble with my player, he doesn't stop when I don't press the arrow keys.

How do I create movement with `KeyPressed`?

I have so far this method code:

```
public void checkInput() {
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP)) {
        player.goUp();
    } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN)) {
        player.goDown();
    } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)) {
        player.goLeft();
    } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)) {
        player.goRight();
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess `go####` set a direction for the `player`, direction used to calculate the next position ? If so, reset the direction when the key is released (or after the position has been updated)

Comment: It would help if you included one of the goXXXX() methods.

Answer (score 0):

When the player has no input it should stop.

```
 ... // youre code
 } else if ( player.isMoving() ) {
     player.stop();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void checkInput() {
    if(Gdx.input.isTouched()==true)
{
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP)) {
        player.goUp();
    } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN)) {
        player.goDown();
    } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)) {
        player.goLeft();
    } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)) {
        player.goRight();
    }
}
else{
//stop
}
}
```